# Task<T> and Task in Func delegate

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, func

I want to cleanup some of my code. I have overloaded method. Can I somehow simplyfy this code and invoke one method in another ? Cant figure out how to do this.

```
private async Task<T> DecorateWithWaitScreen<T>(Func<Task<T>> action)
{
    SplashScreenManager.ShowForm(this, typeof(WaitForm), true, true, false);
    try
    {
        return await action();
        
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        SplashScreenManager.CloseForm(false);
    }
}

private async Task DecorateWithWaitScreen(Func<Task> action)
{
    SplashScreenManager.ShowForm(this, typeof(WaitForm), true, true, false);
    try
    {
        await action();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        SplashScreenManager.CloseForm(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: May be it will be better to post this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Okay, I will do that.

Comment: Did you do it? If so, this thread is obsolete

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov for the record, I see this as a perfectly valid syntax / code question, not a subjective review thing.

Comment: @MarcGravell I thought that this question is more about code review as he has working code and has not any problem except that he wants to do it in other way

Comment: I have 40 min delay for post each question, so I need to do that later.

Answer (score 8):

How about:

```
private Task DecorateWithWaitScreen(Func<Task> action)
    => DecorateWithWaitScreen<int>(async () => { await action(); return 0; });
```

Comment: After @Marc guided me to this solution I think to make ```return Task.CompletedTask;``` looks better.

Comment: @JustBeginner but... that would require that you have `DecorateWithWaitScreen<Task>` ? meh, I guess that's OK, but seems ... odd